# defining several jQuery on click scroll listeners based on an javascript array

Tags: jquery, scroll, click

I've defined "essayList" as an array containing several items which I intend to use to assist building several on-click scroll events for sections of my site using a for loop.

For example, when evaluating "vi", the for loop should build a click event listener which would scroll the page to the element having "#vi" as ID when clicking an element having "#essay-link-vi" as ID.

However, code below makes all click actions scroll to element of ID "I" (last item of array).

```
var index = 0;
var essayList = ['ix', 'viii', 'vii', 'vi', 'v', 'iv', 'iii', 'ii', 'i'];

    for (index = 0; index < essayList.length; ++index) {

        currentAnchor = "#essay-link-" + essayList[index];
        currentTarget = "#" + essayList[index];

        console.log(currentAnchor);
        console.log(currentTarget);

        jQuery(currentAnchor).click(function () {
            jQuery([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
                scrollTop: jQuery(currentTarget).offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
```

I suspect I may have a problem with variable scopes. How can I make this for loop work? console.log reports correct values.

Comment: I think it is indiferent

Comment: been researching here, it is a closure issue, trying to figure out the right code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're trying to achieve:

**Create page**:

```
$('html').css('height', '4000px')
```

**Create anchors**:

```
var index = 0;
var essayList = ['ix', 'viii', 'vii', 'vi', 'v', 'iv', 'iii', 'ii', 'i'];
```

**Dynamically create elements to click**:

```
for (index = 0; index < essayList.length; ++index) {
    sec_ind = index + 1
    $('html').append("<a href='#" + essayList[index] + "' class='butt'>GO TO SECTION" + sec_ind + "</a><br>")
}
```

**Dynamically create section to scroll to**:

```
for (index = 0; index < essayList.length; ++index) {
    sec_ind = index + 1
    $('html').append("<div class='sec' id=" + essayList[index] + ">SECTION " + sec_ind + "</div>")
    $('.sec').css('height', '600px').css('background', 'grey').css('margin-bottom', '10px')
}
```

**Add CSS for smooth scrolling**:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

**Result**:

[image]

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CyberneticSean/581p49ay/3/).

Comment: thanks for all the time preparing the example, unfortunately smooth scroll is still new and not compatible with all browsers so it's not a viable solution

Comment: Right but you can add any scroll approach to your dynamically created elements.